# Generating a list of Strings in Obj C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbundle, nsmutablestring

It seems that Objective C jumps thru hoops to make seemingly simple tasks extremely difficult.

I simply need to create a sequence of strings, `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, etc etc

ie in a loop
`var imgString:String='image'+i+'.jpg;`

I assume a best practice is to use a `NSMutableString` with `appendString` method?

What am I doing wrong??

```
NSMutableString *imgString;

    for(int i=1;i<=NUMIMAGES;i++){
    imgString.appendString(@"image"+i+@".jpg");
}
```

I get the following error

> error: request for member 'appendString' in something not a structure
>   or union

Comment: Gross. Read the basic documentation on Objective-C before asking questions. It's all a lot easier than you think it is, and I assure you that it will come naturally to you once you have read the documentation.

Comment: The problem isn't that Objective-C makes you "jump through hoops" — it's that you haven't learned Objective-C at all. Of course it will look hard if you don't know it. You don't even have the basic syntax right — you're using Javascript method calling syntax. That's literally the second thing taught in Apple's Objective-C tutorial. I suggest you read it or you're in for surprises everywhere: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html

Comment: “I simply need to create a sequence of strings, image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc etc” So then you don't need to *concatenate* strings at all. Concatenation produces a single string, which is what the code you show in your question would do if it were valid.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You are trying to compile Javascript with the Objective-C compiler.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I cannot possibly imagine how yielding the string `image5image4image3image2image1.jpg` in `string3` in your "answer" to your own question could be construed as useful or a solution (I pasted your code into an Xcode Foundation tool project w/NUMIMAGES set to 5).

*It seems that Objective C jumps thru hoops to make seemingly simple tasks extremely difficult.*

Read [the Objective-C Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) and [the String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i), then make draw your conclusions.  Criticizing something you don't understand is generally counter-productive (we've all  done it, though -- easy to do when frustrated).

*I simply need to create a sequence of strings, image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc etc*

### Naive solution:

```
#define NUMIMAGES 5
NSMutableArray *fileNames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    [fileNames addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"image%d.jpg", i]];
NSLog(@"fileNames %@", fileNames);
```

Outputs:

```
fileNames (
    "image0.jpg",
    "image1.jpg",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.jpg",
    "image4.jpg"
)
```

Note that there isn't anything particularly wrong with the naive solution.  It is just more fragile, less efficient, and more code than is necessary.

### One Possible Better Solution

1. Add all images into your application project as resources.
2. Use the NSBundle API to grab URLs to all images at once.

I.e.:

```
NSArray *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType: @"jpg" inDirectory: nil];
```

Not only does this remove hardcoding of image names from your code, it also allows the system to optimize directory enumeration and path generation.   If you want to load only a subset of images -- say you are writing a game and have a series of images related to monsters -- then put all the related images in a single directory, add the directory to your Resources, then pass that directory's name as the second argument to the above method.

All of this -- and much more -- is documented in the [resource programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i).

Comment: Thanks. Will have yo look it up since I'm still unclear how I would then access individual images in the paths array created.

Comment: NSArray documentation is quite clear and even has a companion programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i

Answer (score 7):

First, your syntax for invoking methods is off - i recommend reading through Apples [Introduction to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html). Notably, to invoke a method you use the `[someObject someMethod]` syntax.

The next problem is that you never create the string you are trying to append to, you can use e.g. `[NSMutableString string]` for that.

Continuing, to concatenate a mutable string with some formatted string use [`-appendFormat:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-appendFormat_), e.g.:

```
NSMutableString *imgString = [NSMutableString string];

for (int i=1; i<=NUMIMAGES; i++) {
    if (i > 1) [imgString appendString:@", "];
    [imgString appendFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I’m not really sure what you’re trying to do, but this might be an inspiration:

```
NSMutableArray *fileNames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<max; i++)
    [fileNames addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.jpg", i]];
```

As for your error, you’re using the dot syntax where it doesn’t make any sense. Also, you don’t use the `+` to concatenate strings in Objective-C. The correct `appendString` syntax looks like this:

```
NSMutableString *foo = [NSMutableString string];
[foo appendString:@"Hello, "];
[foo appendString:@"world!"];
```

As you can see on the first line, it is a good idea to initialize objects before you use them :) To concatenate strings you can use the `appendString` method of `NSMutableString` or you can create a new immutable string:

```
NSString *one = @"Hello, ";
NSString *two = [one stringByAppendingString:@"world!"];
```

If you have more strings to concatenate, you can use the `stringWithFormat` initializer:

```
NSString *composed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@!",
     @"Hello", @"Objective-C", @"world"];
```

If you still have the feeling that Objective-C makes certain things extremely difficult you might gain some advantage by actually learning it ;)

Comment: Yes your 1st example is what I need

Answer (score 1):

The simplest code which does what you want would be something like this:

```
NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 1; i <= NUMIMAGES; i++) [string appendFormat: @"image%d.jpg", i];
```

That's it. As you can see, `appendFormat:` really makes things a **lot** easier!  But I can't figure out why you would want to do this.  You'll get something like:

```
"image1.jpgimage2.jpgimage3.jpgimage4.jpgimage5.jpg. . ."
```

What are you actually trying to achieve?
Dave

Answer (score -7):

Appreciate all the answers! 
Sometimes it feels that one needs to be a masochist to be proficient in Objective C!. 
Will try the above but ended up using

```
NSString *string1 = @"image"; 
NSString *string2; 
NSString *string3 = @".jpg"; 
NSString *incString; //*/ 

for(int i=1;i<=NUMIMAGES;i++)
{ 
 incString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]; 
 string2 = [string1 stringByAppendingString:incString]; 
 string3 = [string2 stringByAppendingString:string3]; 
}
```

Comment: You really ought to take a look at the `appendFormat` function, it will make your life easier. See Georg’s answer.

Comment: Sometimes I think people should first try to actually LEARN a language before saying it sucks.

I'm not a masochist and still I like Objective-C a lot, because I actually put some time into learning the language before rushing to get an app in the App Store (assuming that's what you're using Objective-C for).

Comment: What Douwe said.  As written, that code doesn't make sense.